# Comparision of using two dimensional mode or one dimensional in case of optical data transmission

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, research-level, fiber-optics, waveguide

Many works have been done to increase capacity of optical communication. I saw that some researcher using 1-D mode ,some 2-D to implement their device.The reson of using 1-d/2-d beacuse of their types of waveguide they proposed but i want to know  what is the advantage/disadvantage of these two types of mode in case of data communication. Need a detailed description

Link of papers Using 1D modes -->1/ https://www.osapublishing.org/ao/abstract.cfm?uri=ao-53-3-496 2/https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8114815

Link of papers Using 2D modes --> 1/https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6647527 2/https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1068520016300633

Comment: I don't know enough about the context of this question, to give you a solid answer, but I have some guesses that might help you: 1. The modes themselves are likely 2-d in nature, but modes in certain structures might have a convenient symmetry or uniformity that allows them to be analyzed with only 1-d equations. 2. We (people) are lazy so we only want to do as little math as possible. This means using simplified models when they're good enough to solve our problems. 3. One lab might prefer to make the structure that's more difficult to analyze because it's easier for them to manufacture.

Comment: Or because they think it has some performance advantage, or because it solves a slightly different problem, or ...

Comment: where I can find information about 1-d/2-d mode,about their propagation characteristics , how much data they could contain etc etc. what is the difference of TE1/TE11 mode in case of data communication. I actually searching these question's answer.